# ASP.NET Controller instance from View is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When I try to get HomeController from View, it's always null, why ? Is it because I use CodeBehind (see my full source code [Why my button click handler in codebehind is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313723/why-my-button-click-handler-in-codebehind-is-not-called) )

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>
    {


        HomeController HomeController;



        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HomeController = (HomeController)HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["HomeController"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the current controller from the [`ViewContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewcontext%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). It has a [`Controller`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.controller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property:

```
var currentController = ViewContext.Controller;
```

and if you know for sure that it's gonna be HomeController you could cast it:

```
var homeController = (HomeController)ViewContext.Controller;
```

This being said, I am not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve and why on Earth does your view has code behind, but this stinks from very far.

Comment: Totally agreed here with @DarinDimitrov. It makes no sense what you are trying to do. This is not MVC and is webforms but also webforms don't have a concept of a controller. why are you trying to reinvent the wheel or make something so complicated and difficult to maintain and follow through?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I'm just trying to understand all the internals of ASP.NET MVC at the moment.